# R- Calculate a count of items over time using start and end dates

Tags: r, duration, dplyr

I want to calculate a count of items over time using their Start and End dates.

Some sample data

```
START <- as.Date(c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-02","2014-01-03","2014-01-03"))
END <- as.Date(c("2014-01-04", "2014-01-03","2014-01-03","2014-01-04"))
df <- data.frame(START,END)
df
```

gives

```
       START        END
1 2014-01-01 2014-01-04
2 2014-01-02 2014-01-03
3 2014-01-03 2014-01-03
4 2014-01-03 2014-01-04
```

A table showing a count of these items across time (based on their Start and End times) is as follows:

```
DATETIME    COUNT
2014-01-01   1 
2014-01-02   2 
2014-01-03   4 
2014-01-04   2
```

Can this be done using R, especially using dplyr? Many thanks.

Comment: @RichardScriven. Each row defines a period from START to END. `2014-01-03` for example is part of all four periods shown here.

Answer (score 7):

This would do it. You can change the column names as necessary.

```
as.data.frame(table(Reduce(c, Map(seq, df$START, df$END, by = 1))))
#         Var1 Freq
# 1 2014-01-01    1
# 2 2014-01-02    2
# 3 2014-01-03    4
# 4 2014-01-04    2
```

As noted in the comments, `Var1` in the above solution is now a factor, and not a date.  To keep the date class in the first column, you could do some more work to the above solution, or use `plyr::count` instead of `as.data.frame(table(...))`

```
library(plyr)
count(Reduce(c, Map(seq, df$START, df$END, by = 1)))
#            x freq
# 1 2014-01-01    1
# 2 2014-01-02    2
# 3 2014-01-03    4
# 4 2014-01-04    2
```

Comment: Note that it still works if `Reduce` is replaced by `do.call` .

Comment: Beware that `Var1` is now a factor, not a date.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df)[, list(DATETIME= seq(START, END, by=1)), by=1:nrow(df)][,
                           list(COUNT=.N), by=DATETIME]
 DT
 #     DATETIME COUNT
 #1: 2014-01-01     1
 #2: 2014-01-02     2
 #3: 2014-01-03     4
 #4: 2014-01-04     2
```

---

From version 1.9.4+, you can also use the function `foverlaps()` to do an "overlap join". It's more efficient as it doesn't have to expand the dates for each row first, and then count. Here's how:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4
setDT(df) ## convert your data.frame to data.table by reference

## 1. Some preprocessing:
# create a lookup - the dates for which you need the count, and set key
dates = seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"), as.Date("2014-01-04"), by="days")
lookup = data.table(START=dates, END=dates, key=c("START", "END"))

## 2. Now find overlapping coordinates 
# for each row in `df` get all the rows it overlaps with in `lookup`
ans = foverlaps(df, lookup, type="any", which=TRUE)
```

Now, we just have to group by `yid` (= indices in `lookup`) and count:

```
## 3. count
ans[, .N, by=yid]
#    yid N
# 1:   1 1
# 2:   2 2
# 3:   3 4
# 4:   4 2
```

The first column corresponds to the row numbers in `lookup`. If some numbers are missing, then the count  is 0 for them.

Comment: This is a case for overlap joins using `foverlaps()` by creating another data.table with the desired dates OP wants to find the overlaps for. Want to give it a try.

Comment: @Arun Thank you for editing and showing the `foverlaps`.

Comment: My goodness. As a new R user I am amazed with the wide variety of approaches available to solving such questions. I have some catching up to do. Also, thanks to  Richard Scriven for clarifying my question. I greatly appreciate the help all have provided. This is terrific.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr and grouped data:

```
data_frame(
            START = as.Date(c("2014-01-01", "2014-01-02","2014-01-03","2014-01-03")),
            END   = as.Date(c("2014-01-04", "2014-01-03","2014-01-03","2014-01-04"))
           ) -> df
rbind(cbind(group = 'a', df),cbind(group = 'b', df)) %>% as_data_frame->df
df

df %>% 
  group_by(.,group) %>% 
  do(data.frame(table(Reduce(c, Map(seq, .$START, .$END, by = 1)))))
```

This is a common problem when you for example want to find the number of logins on different pages/machines etc given time-intervals per users

```
> df
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]

  group      START        END
  (chr)     (date)     (date)
1     a 2014-01-01 2014-01-04
2     a 2014-01-02 2014-01-03
3     a 2014-01-03 2014-01-03
4     a 2014-01-03 2014-01-04
5     b 2014-01-01 2014-01-04
6     b 2014-01-02 2014-01-03
7     b 2014-01-03 2014-01-03
8     b 2014-01-03 2014-01-04
> 
> df %>% 
+   group_by(.,group) %>% 
+   do(data.frame(table(Reduce(c, Map(seq, .$START, .$END, by = 1)))))
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: group [2]

  group       Var1  Freq
  (chr)     (fctr) (int)
1     a 2014-01-01     1
2     a 2014-01-02     2
3     a 2014-01-03     4
4     a 2014-01-04     2
5     b 2014-01-01     1
6     b 2014-01-02     2
7     b 2014-01-03     4
8     b 2014-01-04     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `foreach`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(foreach)

df <- data.frame(START = as.Date(c("2014-01-01",
                                   "2014-01-02",
                                   "2014-01-03",
                                   "2014-01-03")),
                 END = as.Date(c("2014-01-04",
                                 "2014-01-03",
                                 "2014-01-03",
                                 "2014-01-04")))
df

r <- foreach(DATETIME = seq(min(df$START), max(df$END), by = 1),
             .combine = rbind) %do% {
  df %>%
    filter(DATETIME >= START & DATETIME <= END) %>%
    summarise(DATETIME, COUNT = n())
}
r
```

Answer (score 0):

I just proposed another lubridate-based solution that's faster for larger dataframes with wide date ranges in a newer and related SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909192/3124533)