# How to count records with start date end date interval in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with items, and for every item a start date and an end date is available. I would like to know how many items are active for every day in a time period.

Example data set:

```
ItemId <- c(1,2,3)
StartDate <- c(ymd("2014-01-01"),ymd("2014-02-01"),ymd("2014-03-01"))
EndDate <- c(ymd("2014-02-15"),ymd("2014-02-07"),ymd("2014-03-03"))
data.frame(ItemId,StartDate,EndDate)
  ItemId           StartDate             EndDate
1      1 2014-01-01 01:00:00 2014-02-15 01:00:00
2      2 2014-02-01 01:00:00 2014-02-07 01:00:00
3      3 2014-03-01 01:00:00 2014-03-03 01:00:00
```

The result should look something like this (one entry for every day):

```
Date        ActiveCount
2014-01-01  1
2014-01-02  1
...
2014-02-01  2
...
```

I have a solution using sqldf, but not sure how to do this in R.

```
select d.date
,      ( select count(ItemID)
         from   items
         where  startdate <= d.date
         and    enddate >= d.date
       ) activecount
from   (select distinct startdate from items
        union
        select distinct enddate from items
       ) d
order by 1
```

(My contains multiple entries for every day, so for sqlite in R this works. On postgresql i can generate a series of dates which is better.)

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at `foverlaps()` from `data.table` package. Or search for it here on SO.

Comment: Note that the sql statement could use `where d.date is between startdate and enddate` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever an R task resembles a SQL task, its probably time to bring `dplyr` out of the cupboard:

```
library(dplyr) 
ItemId <- c(1,2,3)
StartDate <- c(ymd("2014-01-01"),ymd("2014-02-01"),ymd("2014-03-01"))
EndDate <- c(ymd("2014-02-15"),ymd("2014-02-07"),ymd("2014-03-03"))

jim <- data.frame(ItemId,StartDate,EndDate)

# One technique that's often useful especially in R, is to take your 
# iterator, and define it as a variable.  You can use that to implement
# a vectorised version of whatever you were thinking of doing.*/

ed <- data.frame(rng = seq(min(jim$StartDate), max(jim$EndDate), by = 'day'))
merge(jim, ed, all=TRUE) %>% 
     filter(rng >= StartDate, rng <= EndDate) %>%
     group_by(rng) %>% 
     summarise(n())
```

And that gives you:

```
    rng         n()
1   2014-01-01  1 
2   2014-01-02  1
3   2014-01-03  1
...
```

Answer (score 9):

Calling your data `df`:

```
dates = seq(min(df$StartDate), max(df$EndDate), by = "day")

counts = data.frame(date = dates,
                    count = sapply(dates, function(x) sum(x <= df$EndDate & x >= df$StartDate)))
```

Answer (score 5):

I've come back to this problem a number of times and am constantly looking for the most efficient approach.

I've previously used a map-reduce approach but noticed it doesn't scale well to large dataframes with wide date intervals. I just tried using the `interval` class from the `lubridate` package and found it to be the fastest implementation so far.

Here's the final code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Initialize a dataframe with start and end "active" dates per object
N = 1000
id_dates = tibble(id = 1 : N) %>%
  mutate(
    start = sample(seq(as.Date('2018-1-1'), as.Date('2019-1-1'), by = "day"), size = N, replace = TRUE),
    end   = start + sample(7 : 100, size = N, replace = TRUE),
    interval = interval(start, end))

# Use the %within% command to calculate the number of active items per date
queue_history = tibble(Date = seq(min(id_dates$start), max(id_dates$end), by = "1 day")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(numInWIP = sum(Date %within% id_dates$interval)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Here are some benchmarks showing that the lubridate solution is far faster than both the current answer and a map-reduce approach

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Initialize a dataframe with start and end "active" dates per object
N = 1000
id_dates = tibble(id = 1 : N) %>%
  mutate(
    start = sample(seq(as.Date('2018-1-1'), as.Date('2019-1-1'), by = "day"), size = N, replace = TRUE),
    end   = start + sample(7 : 100, size = N, replace = TRUE),
    interval = interval(start, end))

# a map-reduce solution
method_mapreduce = function() {
  queue_history = as.tibble(table(reduce(map2(id_dates$start, id_dates$end, seq, by = 1), c)))
  queue_history = queue_history %>%
    rename(Date = Var1, numInWIP = Freq) %>%
    mutate(Date = as_date(Date))

  return (queue_history)
}

# a lubridate interval solution
method_intervals = function() {
  date_df = tibble(Date = seq(min(id_dates$start), max(id_dates$end), by = "1 day"))
  queue_history = date_df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(numInWIP = sum(Date %within% id_dates$interval))

  return (queue_history)
}

# current best answer
method_currentsolution = function() {
  date_df = tibble(Date = seq(min(id_dates$start), max(id_dates$end), by = "1 day"))
  queue_history = merge(id_dates, date_df, all=TRUE) %>% 
    filter(Date >= start, Date <= end) %>%
    group_by(Date) %>% 
    summarise(n())

}

# Compare with benchmarks
tst = microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  method_mapreduce(),
  method_intervals(),
  method_currentsolution(),
  times = 5)

microbenchmark::autoplot.microbenchmark(tst) +
  scale_y_log10(
    name   = sprintf("Time [%s]", attr(summary(tst), "unit")),
    breaks = scales::trans_breaks("log10", function(x) round(10^x)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there, apologies for reviving such an old post, but I am running into a similar problem as OP and wanted to implement your code. However, rather than trying to find the number of records per day, I need to find the number of records per year (from start and end dates). How could I adapt your method to do this? Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You first want to get all dates with at least one active item, then you want to count the number of active items on each day. If we store your data from in `itemDates` then this should take care of it:

```
dates <- min(itemDates$StartDate) + days(0:as.numeric(max(itemDates$EndDate) - min(itemDates$StartDate)))
dateCounts <- data.frame(
    row.names=dates,
    counts=sapply(dates, function(date)
        sum(date >= itemDates$StartDate & date <= itemDates$EndDate)))
```