# R - count of items in line chart: match DateTime to count of items

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(1:9, .Label = c("task 1", "task 2", 
"task 3", "task 4", "task 5", "task 6", "task 7", "task 8", "task 9"
), class = "factor"), Start = structure(c(1479799800, 1479800100, 
1479800400, 1479800700, 1479801000, 1479801300, 1479801600, 1479801900, 
1479802200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), End = structure(c(1479801072, 
1479800892, 1479801492, 1479802092, 1479802692, 1479803292, 1479803892, 
1479804492, 1479805092), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Start", "End"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now I want to count the items in column "Name" over time. They all have a start and end datetimes, which are formated as POSIXct.

With help of [this solution here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290314/r-calculate-a-count-of-items-over-time-using-start-and-end-dates) I was able to do so (or at least I think I was) with following code:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dates = seq(min(df$Start), max(df$End), by = "min")
lookup = data.table(Start = dates, End = dates, key = c("Start", "End"))
ans = foverlaps(df, lookup, type = "any", which = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(ans[, .N, by = yid], aes(x = yid, y = N)) + geom_line()
```

Problem now:

How do I match my DateTime-scale to those integer values on the x-axis? Or is there a faster and better solution to solve my problem?

I tried to use `x = as.POSIXct(yid, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", origin = min(df$Start))` within the `aes` of the `ggplot()`. But that didn't work.

EDIT:

When using the solution for this problem, I face another. Items, where there is no count, are displayed with the count of the latest countable item in the plot. This is why we have to merge (leftjoin) the table with the counts (`ants`) again with a complete sequence of all Datetimes and put a `0` for every `NA`. So we get explicit values for every necessary datapoint.
Like this:

```
# The part we use to count and match the right times
df1 <- ans[, .N, by = yid] %>%
mutate(time = min(df$Start) + minutes(yid))
# The part where we use the sequence from the beginning for a LEFT JOIN with the counting dataframe
df2 <- data.frame(time = dates)
dt <- merge(x = df2, y = df1, by = "time", all.x = TRUE)
dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `tidyverse` framework, this is a slightly different task -

1. Generate the sames `dates` variable you have.
2. Construct a data frame with all dates and all times (cartesian join)
3. Filter out the rows that are not in the interval for each task
4. Add up the tasks for each minute that remain
5. Plot.

That looks something like this --

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dates = seq(min(df$Start), max(df$End), by = "min")
df %>% 
  mutate(key = 1) %>% 
  left_join(data_frame(key = 1, times = dates)) %>% 
  mutate(include = times %within% interval(Start, End)) %>% 
  filter(include) %>% 
  group_by(times) %>% 
  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(times, count)) +
  geom_line()
#> Joining, by = "key"
```

[image]

If you need it to be faster, it will almost certainly be faster using your original `data.table` code.

Consider this.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dates = seq(min(df$Start), max(df$End), by = "min")
lookup = data.table(Start = dates, End = dates, key = c("Start", "End"))
ans = foverlaps(df, lookup, type = "any", which = TRUE)

ans[, .N, by = yid] %>%
  mutate(time = min(df$Start) + minutes(yid)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, N)) +
  geom_line()
```

Now we use `data.table` to calculate the overlap, and then index time off the starting minute. Once we add a new column with the times, we can plot.

[image]

Comment: Seems to work, thank you! Only problem is, that it kills my notebook, when I insert the original dataset :D I guess I will have to enlarge the timeframes from minutes to something like 30 mins to ensure the join doesn't allocate too much RAM.

Comment: Well, that is the most expensive way to do it. There are technically faster ways.... Let me see.

Comment: @Talvien I added an example with `data.table`.

Comment: Seems to work, but I got another problem with the real data. Even though there are no items running the count displayed is "2". I added the data to my original post, so you can see it. Could it be that it doesn't count if there are no values so it stays visually on the count of the latest item?

Comment: I added geom_point() to see where real count values are. And yes, the problem is that the count isn't set to 0 if there are no items to count in a timeframe.

Comment: Problem solved: I add the solution to the original entry