# How can I get the number of units in an age group over a time period?

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I am trying to find an efficient way to get the total population by age over a time period. I have birthdays, a start date, and an end date (for being in a program):

```
people <- data.frame(start_date = as.Date(c("2005-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01"), 
              end_date = as.Date(c(NA, NA, "2008-01-01"), 
              bday = as.Date(c("1983-01-01", "1985-01-01", "1986-01-01")))
```

I would like to end up with something that shows the number of 21, 22, 23, etc year olds from 2005-2015. Put differently, the number of people that were ever in an age group over the time interval. In this example:

```
AGE   COUNT
20     2
21     2
22     2
23     3
24     2
25     2
```

To add another wrinkle, I am using dbplyr to work with sql databases, so I'm looking for a dbplyr or sql solution. There are about 30 million people here, so the heavy lifting has to be done that way.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290314/r-calculate-a-count-of-items-over-time-using-start-and-end-dates) but not quite the same, and not database friendly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, but it may not be the most efficient approach:

First, find a "minage" and "maxage" for each person, in months here:

```
DATEDIFF(m, start_date, bday)
DATEDIFF(m, end_date, bday)
```

Then pull this into R with dbplyr collect into "mydata". Finally, lapply through all months between ages 18 and 100:

```
month_list <- as.list(216:1200) 
all <- lapply(month_list, function(x) {
    mydata %>%
       mutate(in_range = ifelse(x >= abs(minage) & x <= abs(maxage),1,0))%>%    
       summarise(count = sum(in_range, na.rm=T)
})
```