# mysql: get running count over time based on start and end timestamps

Tags: sql, mysql, running-count

I have a `workflows` table with columns (`processID`, `started_at`, `ended_at`)

How can I build running `counts` of actively running process IDs per a given timestamp as a timeseries from data tabulated below:

Table of process timestamps:

```
id      started_at              ended_at
------- --------------------    --------------------
1203914 2023-04-20T04:54:29Z    2023-04-20T20:43:53Z
1197674 2023-04-20T06:00:28Z    2023-04-20T21:17:53Z
1212050 2023-04-20T18:47:29Z    0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
1198434 2023-04-22T18:16:53Z    2023-04-22T19:02:59Z
1210450 2023-04-22T19:06:53Z    2023-04-26T03:23:39Z
1210466 2023-04-23T05:34:53Z    2023-04-25T07:09:39Z
1201986 2023-04-24T06:30:53Z    2023-04-24T23:49:53Z
1200122 2023-04-24T17:22:53Z    2023-04-25T05:29:39Z
1209114 2023-04-25T01:07:53Z    2023-04-26T23:03:39Z
1198570 2023-04-25T01:10:53Z    2023-04-27T00:59:38Z
```

expected running process list:

```
timestamp               running_process_count
--------------------    ---------------------
2023-04-20T04:54:29Z    1
2023-04-20T06:00:28Z    2
2023-04-20T18:47:29Z    3
2023-04-22T18:16:53Z    1
2023-04-22T19:06:53Z    1
2023-04-23T05:34:53Z    2
2023-04-24T06:30:53Z    3
2023-04-24T17:22:53Z    4
2023-04-25T01:07:53Z    4
```

I'm looking for something similar to how it's done in:

[R- Calculate a count of items over time using start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290314/r-calculate-a-count-of-items-over-time-using-start-and-end-dates)

I can get counts of process IDs for a particular HOUR by using the following query, however what I'm looking for is "running" process count per timestamp (can be started_at) where we display count of processes that have started_at < timestamp < ended_at.

Do I need to use MySQL windowing functions to achieve this? (lag, lead, partition etc) - apologize as I'm not familiar with advanced MySQL operators.

What I have so far:

```
SELECT   
  started_at,
  count(*) AS running_count
FROM workflows
GROUP BY 
  YEAR(started_at),
  MONTH(started_at),
  DAY(started_at),
  HOUR(started_at)
ORDER BY 
  YEAR(started_at),
  MONTH(started_at),
  DAY(started_at),
  HOUR(started_at);
```

Comment: Are you running this on your complete dataset?  Or do you only need timestamps in a certain range but need to accommodate some running processes from earlier?  It looks like you only want rows for times when processes started, not also when they end; is that correct?

Comment: @rajivRaja `0001-01-01T00:00:00Z` here is good date ?

Comment: @ysth I'm planning to run this on complete data set of 17k records. Trying to visualize this as a time series graph and filter by time ranges on the UI. As far as processes that don't end, we can include them as part of running count for timestamps >= started_at through NOW() if that makes sense.

Comment: @Nickname_used - Yes, we can use 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z as default for ended_at for processes that are still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a self-join and aggregate as the following:

```
select t1.started_at,
  count(t2.id) cnt
from workflows t1 left join workflows t2
on t1.started_at between t2.started_at and t2.ended_at
group by t1.started_at
order by t1.started_at
```

[See a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PJbRBHhk)

Comment: Thanks! This works really well for large data sets as well! [1337 rows in set (2.90 sec)].

Comment: You are welcome, just a note, for processes that are still running you have to use a date in the future for endded_at.

Comment: Adding two separate indexes on started_at and end_at, *may* improve the performance here, but be aware of the side effects of poor performance while using INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements. https://dbfiddle.uk/71fvKsfu

Comment: Using this condition works as expected for my case: `ON (t1.started_at BETWEEN t2.started_at AND t2.ended_at) OR (t2.started_at <  t1.started_at AND t2.ended_at like '%0001-01-01%')` since we set default ended_at to 1/1/1. But in general case we could do something like  `t2.ended_at = @MaxCollatingDate`